# Chrome jquery ajax callback on success not firing

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery

As far as I know, `$.ajax` has always worked pretty smoothly in every browser until now.
I have a pretty simple function, called when a couple of actions from the user occur.
In Firefox, everything runs smoothly. But in Chrome, while the `$.ajax` request is launched, the callback on success doesn't fire.

Here's the actual snippet:

```
    var form  = $("#templateCreator"),
    formType  = form.attr("method"),
    formData  = form.serialize(),
    action    = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: formType,
        url: action,
        data: formData,
        success: function(){
            console.log('Can\'t see me in Chrome, but ok in firefox !')

            // Handle all form submit events to form validator first
            validator(form, targetInput);
        }
    });
```

What's puzzling is nothing seems wrong, data is serialized, and sent properly. Does anyone know what I missed?

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of the variables used in your AJAX call (`formType`/`formData`/`action`)? And are you relying on the `validator()` function to run to verify that it works or have you tried putting a `console.log()` as the first line of your `success` callback?

Comment: localhost? If true that why it doesn't work. Chrome doesn't allow AJAX on localhost

Comment: @AndreasAL, you're doin' localhost wrong.

Comment: It would probably useful to capture the error state as well rather than just success, just saying... good practice and all that.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of to debug would be to set `complete` and `error` callback functions to diagnose the issue via callback arguments.

Comment: @Esailija - lol to fast for my brain . Don't know what I'm talking about.. sry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by adding an error and complete method as @Jasper suggested.

```
$.ajax({
        type: formType,
        url: action,
        data: formData,
        success: function(){
            console.log('Can\'t see me in Chrome, but ok in firefox !')

            // Handle all form submit events to form validator first
            validator(form, targetInput);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
        }
    });
```

Then you can:

1. open Chrome debugger (F12), go to the scripts tag, and put a breakpoint inside success/complete/error; check out the stack trace and values for an epiphany ;)
2. have a look at the console logs
3. For great joy, take off every Zig!

Comment: Thanks. While not giving me the answer, you gave me some slight enlightenment on how to debug this. Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you don't have other .ajax() functions firing for the same click. I included a few files that had the same $('element').click() function which triggered the .ajax() call. Beginner mistake but even vets do it sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and set async: false. This works for me in Chrome. Looks like Chrome has an issue with async: true.

```
   restget = function(url, cb){
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        success: cb
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this .....

data: formData,
async: false,

Chrome has some issues with async calls.

Comment: Don't do this. It has more problems than not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to get a json array. I had to add `dataType: 'json'` to my ajax so that non-Firefox browsers know what my data type is. For instance:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo",
    success: function(data){
        var jsonArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(jsonArray.status.message);
    }
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var jsonArray = data;
        alert(jsonArray.status.message);
    }
});
```

will display the same thing when ran in Firefox firebug. But when you run this in Chrome DevTools it will only work on the bottom one. I hope this fixes your problem.